# Django ForeignKey related field with localization of ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have a custom user model with a country field and I am using django-cities's Country model as a ForignKey. I also want to use localization for country names. (I cannot import alt_names of django-cities for localization so that option is off the table). In my forms.py I try to give choice fields with

```
# forms.py 
from cities.models import Country
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    c = Country.objects.all()
    country_choices = [(Country.objects.filter(id=c[i].id),  c[i].name ) for i in range(len(c)) ]
    country_choices_localize = [(c[0], _('{0}'.format(c[1]))) for c in country_choices]
    country = 
    forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple(country_choices_localize), initial=None)

# view.py    
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
```

This does not seem to work.Django stops at form validation `if form.is_valid():` I get ValueError for Country.objects.filter(id=c[i].id). Saying that MyUser.country must be 'Country' instance.
Is there a work around to use localization in ChoiceField along with Country model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you get a ValuError because the form would wait for an instance of Country, not an integer (as id). I suggest you to first exclude `country` from your form  fields, then add a temporary field called `country_temp`, and work with this field

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['country']
        model = YourUserModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        country_choices = [(country.id, _(country.name)) for country in Country.objects.all()] # get all countries o filter as you need
        country_temp = forms.ChoiceField(choices=country_choices, required=True)
```

And in your view get the right instance

```
# view.py
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False

            # validate some conditions to Country choice, if you need
            user.country = Country.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data.get("country_temp"))
            user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your list comprehension is nonsense. You get all countries, then loop through a range based on the length, then get the item from the original list, then separately query the item from the database again? That really is not how you do Python. And there is no need for the separate localise list comprehension either. It should just be:

```
country_choices_localised = [(i.id, _(i.name)) for i in c]
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, this solution does not work `i.id`  gives integer, but MyUser.country expects 'Country' instance. Am I missing  something?

Comment: Presumably this is happening when you save the form. You need to show that code and the full traceback.